# Create a function with variable acguments (strings) which outputs that strings ant count them

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm new at C. And I still don't really get pointers. Could someone help me, please.
I have to create a function with variable arguments (strings) which outputs that strings ant count them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintAndCount(const char* s, ...)
{
    char **p = &s;
    while(*p != NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", *p);
      (*p)++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "It was a bright cold day in April.";
    char s2[] = "The hallway smelt of boiled cabbage and old rag mats. ";
    char s3[] = "It was no use trying the lift.";

    PrintAndCount(s1, s2, s3, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable arguments don't use pointers. You need to use the macros in `stdarg.h`. Seems like you need to read a tutorial on processing variable argument lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly iterate though a set of variable arguments, since how they're passed to a function is highly implementation specific.

Instead, use a `va_list` to iterate through them.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void PrintAndCount(const char* s, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, s);

    printf("%s\n", s);
    char *p = va_arg(args, char *);
    while(p != NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n", p);
      p = va_arg(args, char *);
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```